# Accessing host machine from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a java back-end hosted on my windows 10 machine(at localhost:8080). My front-end(.NET project) is hosted inside IIS container and it needs to communicate with the back-end. However, I cannot connect to the host from the container. I could ping the host's IP address with success. But when I use curl to access the host, it just fails with "Unable to connect to the remote server" error. An interesting thing is that I also have MSSQL server running on my Windows 10 machine and my front-end communicates with it using host's computer name without any issue.

Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
Docker Compose 3.4

**UPDATE**

Turns out Port 8080 is blocked at my work. To rephrase my question, does windows container have host domain similar to what linux container offers - host.docker.internal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using docker-compose and you want to connect to your local host from a container you have to use the `host.docker.internal` variable.

For example:

```
services: 
  service1:
    network_mode: host
    environment:
       LOCAL_DB_HOST: host.docker.internal
```

Comment: I got "network host not found " error. I had also tried host.docker.internal inside an environment file and doesn't work. And as i said my original post, I have no problem connecting to my DB server hosted in the host environment using host computer name. It just that I cannot connect to my backend service.